# Why does % always show in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

when I use `printf` function in Visual Studio Code
there is always `%` character at the end of the line in terminal.
why dose this happen?? [image]

Comment: Try `printf("hello\n");` instead.

Comment: It's the shells way to say that the output of the program doesn't end with a newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is your terminal's shell prompt. You have not printed a newline character, so the prompt appears immediately after your program's output.

```
printf("hello\n");
```